# Laravel, multiple file deleting in foreach

Tags: laravel

I wanna delete files from server by database ids.
I'm trying to do this in foreach loop.
Single file deleting is ok but, when user sends multiple file (by checkbox)
my loop deletes only first.

```
public function postSil(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->input('sil');
    foreach($ids as $id)
    {
        $file = File::find($id)->first();
        $path = public_path().'/rea-files/'.$file->rea_number.'/'.$file->file_name;
        \File::delete($path);
       // echo 'id';



    }
   //return 1;
    File::destroy($ids); //this is model file.
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

As you can see, i tried if foreach loop works as well, placed echo and return  and i see foreach loop is working but only deletes first file.

Comment: Have you check the paths to the files are correct in all iteration of the foreach loop?

Comment: Do some check as below `if (! \File::exists($path)) { dd($path); }` This will print the path if there is no file for the given path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved. I used array in File::delete()

Answer (score 0):

just try below code

(case A) User fields indexed by number 0,1,2..

> ```
> $users_to_delete = array(
>    '0'=> array('1','Frank','Smith','Whatever'), 
>    '1'=> array('5','John','Johnson','Whateverelse'),
> );
>
> $ids_to_delete = array_map(function($item){ return $item[0]; }, $users_to_delete);
>
> DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $ids_to_delete)->delete();
> ```

//(case B) User fields indexed by key

```
$users_to_delete = array(
   '0'=> array('id'=>'1','name'=>'Frank','surname'=>'Smith','title'=>'Whatever'),

   '1'=> array('id'=>'5','name'=>'John','surname'=>'Johnson','title'=>'Whateverelse'),
);

$ids_to_delete = array_map(function($item){ return $item['id']; }, $users_to_delete);

DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $ids_to_delete)->delete();
```

Case c

> $ids = array( '0' => 1, '1' => 2);
>
> DB::table('users')->whereIn('id',$ids)->delete();